# Why is it that when I pass a Model to my .Net MVC 4 Controller Action it insists on using it in the Partial Update?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am intending to pass a **Hotel** model to my Controller Action - Do some checks/processing on it, then return a potentially different **Hotel** model rendered in a Partial View.

The problem I'm getting is that if I pass the ***oHotelParameter*** Model to the Action then the PartialView uses the model passed to the Action instead of the one passed to the PartialView method.

If I remove the ***oHotelParameter*** Parameter from the Action then the View is Rendered as expected using ***oHotel***.

```
    public ActionResult _SaveMasterDetails(Hotel oHotelParameter)
    {
        //Do some processing on oHotelParameter

        //........
        Hotel oHotel = new Hotel();
        oHotel.GetHotelInfoById(14); //This gets a different Hotel object just for a test

        //For some reason oHotel is ignored and oHotelParameter is used instead unless I remove oHotelParameter 
        return PartialView("_MasterDetails", oHotel);
    }
```

When I debug the View I see that the Model is set to the value I pass to PartialView (***oHotel***), yet the result I see coming back from the Action contains data from the ***oHotelParameter*** object.

In case it makes a difference, I am calling the Action from jQuery ajax.

Can anyone explain why this should happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when mvc handles a form post, it fills the ModelState object with the details of the model.

This is when used when the view is rendered again from the post action, this is incase you have thrown the view back out because it has failed validation.

If you want to pass out a new model and not use the view state, then you can call ModelState.Clear() before returning the view and that should let you rebind the view to the new model.

Comment: Thanks @Slicksim for that 'little gem' of information. I tried it and it worked. I think I'll need to read that book I've just ordered ASAP. There are clearly things going on that I need to learn -

Answer (score 3):

I think that it would help if you had a better understanding of how model binding works when you post back to an action method.  In most cases, it is unecessary and inefficient to pass a view model as a parameter to a POST action method.   What you are doing is loading the view model into memory twice when you pass your view model as a parameter (assuming a strongly typed view).  When you do a post back the model becomes part of the form collection (through model binding) in the request object in the BaseController class that every controller inherits from.  All that you need to do is to extract the model from the Form collection in the Request object in the BaseController.   It just so happens that there is a handy method, TryUpdateModel to help you do this.   Here is how you do it

```
[POST]
public ActionResult Save()
{
    var saveVm = new SaveViewModel();

    // TryUpdateModel automatically populates your ViewModel!
    // TryUpdateModel also calls ModelState.IsValid and returns
    // true if your model is valid (validation attributes etc.)
    if (TryUpdateModel(saveVm)
    {
        // do some work
        int id = 1;
        var anotherSaveVm = GetSaveVmBySomeId(id);

        // do more work with saveVm and anotherSaveVm
        // clear the existing model
        ModelState.Clear();
        return View(anotherSaveVm);
    }
    // return origonal view model so that the user can correct their errors
    return View(saveVm);
}
```

I think that the data in the form collection contained in the request object is being returned with the view.   When you pass the model back to the post action method as a parameter, I believe it is passed in the query string (see Request.QueryString).  Most of the time, it is best to only pass one or two primitive type parameters or primitive reverence types such as int?  to an action method.   There is no need to pass the entire model as it is already contained in the Form collection of the Request object.   If you wish to examine the QueryString, seee Request.QueryString.